# Sort Python Dictionary based on Values

Tags: python, dictionary, attributes

I have the following program which reads from a tsv file and imports to a dictionary. I need to sort the dictionary based on jobID and its giving me this error:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'jobid'

```
  apps = {}
  for row in csvreader:
    apps[counter]= {'userid': row[0], 'time': row[1], 'jobid': row[2]}
    counter = counter + 1

  sorted_keys = sorted(apps.keys(), key=lambda x:apps.jobid)
```

Any an all help is appreciated.

sample output for the first three rows in the dict:

```
{'jobid': 'JobID', 'userid': 'UserID', 'time': 'ApplicationDate'}

{'jobid': '169528', 'userid': '47', 'time': '2012-04-04 15:56:23.537'}

{'jobid': '284009', 'userid': '47', 'time': '2012-04-06 01:03:00.003'}
```

Thank You!

Comment: Dictionaries are *unordered*. Also, given the use of `counter`, don't you just want a list?

Comment: what is counter doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to use `apps[x]["jobid"]` instead of `apps.jobid`.

Comment: I did that and got : KeyError: 'jobid'

Comment: Reload my answer, I missed a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a list for apps. Then you can sort on jobid by using the dictionary lookup syntax x['jobid'].  Here it is working with sample data:

```
csvreader = (
    ('user1', '2pm', 2),
    ('user2', '2pm', 3),
    ('user3', '2pm', 1)
)

apps = []
for row in csvreader:
    apps.append({'userid': row[0], 'time': row[1], 'jobid': row[2]})

sorted_data = sorted(apps, key=lambda x:x['jobid'])
```